# Call task or function via VPI

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vpi

I know that it's possible to change the values of signals and variables via the Verilog Programming Interface (VPI). It's also possible to trigger a named event, by doing a `vpi_put_value(...)` on it.

Is it somehow possible to call a function or to start a task?

Answer (score 1):

The VPI does not let you call tasks or functions from C, but the DPI does. Technically, the DPI only allows you to call SystemVerilog routines from C routines that have been called from SystemVerilog. The DPI has an import/export mechanism that needs to maintain the process identities of all threads created by your SystemVerilog code.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. Going through the DPI means that I have to export the function. What I wanted to do is get a handle to a class object and use the VPI to call it's functions (i.e. reflection).

Comment: You can't pass class handles across the language boundary. What you need to do is create a wrapper function that you can export and that function can call the class method.